# Request Input From User Side

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, crm

hi there I wonder if I can open a popup on the user side to request input in real-time while I am filling the form

Example:
register customer details in CRM, and there is a customer screen showing some advertising or even remote communication
when I need to fill the form and asking the customer for his number I only click button and popup show in his screen and he can write his number

please check the attachment
[image: example]

there is any way to do it in PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only open one modal page. and you can use Ajax for send values to server